# Xor encryption in PHP server and c++ client

Tags: php, c++, encryption

I have  a c++ client that send encrypted data to my site using XOR encryption. But as a result I have different values in php and c++ code, but I don't understand why?

c++ code snippet

```
string XOR(string value,string key)
{ 
    string text = "";
    DWORD k = 0;
    DWORD v = 0;
    DWORD klen = key.length();
    DWORD vlen = value.length();

    for ( DWORD v = 0; v < vlen; v ++ )
    {
        text +=  value[v] ^ key[k]; 
        k=(++k < klen ? k : 0);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Php code snippet:

```
public  function xorEncrypt( $InputString, $KeyPhrase )
{ 
    $textOut = "";
    $k = 0;
    $klen = strlen($KeyPhrase);

    for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen($InputString); $i++ )
    {
        $textOut .= chr(ord($InputString[$i]) ^ $KeyPhrase[$k]); 
        $k=(++$k < $klen ? $k : 0);
    }

    return $textOut;
}
```

Can anybode help me. Thanks!

Comment: What you haven't encryption. At best it's obfuscation. If you need secure communications, why not use an SSL link instead?

Comment: XOR "encryption" is pretty much useless at it can be deciphered with ease.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the fact that PHP has no DWORD type, so it's performing the XOR on integers of different length. You might have to do the XOR on a byte-by-byte basis to get the same results in PHP and C++.

Comment: And to echo what @Marc B and @silkfire said: this is inadequate encryption. If SSL is not an option, why not try encrypting with `mcrypt` (and whatever the corresponding library is in c++).